# Combining plots in Show[] shifts them weirdly

Tags: plotting, graphics, logarithmic-scale

I have two plots for the same function `func1[x_,y_]:= Exp[x]-y`. One is plotted in "fake" log-linear manner as:

`p1 = ContourPlot[func1[10^(x),y] == 0,{x,-3,1},{y,0.1,10.}]` (the x-axis is "log" scale) and the plot is:

[image: pic1]

The other is plotted using the in-built `LogLinearPlot[]` function as:

`p2 = LogLinearPlot[Exp[x], {x,10^(-3),10}, PlotRange -> {Automatic,{0.1,10}}, PlotStyle -> Green]` and the plot is:

[image: pic2]

Then, I combine them using `Show[p1,p2]`. And since the I expect them to coincide, but instead I get the following graph (blue is `p1` and green is `p2`):

[image: pic3]

I don't understand why the two graphs don't coincide...? I checked and the green graph is shifted (and si wrong) while the blue one is correct (at `y=10`, `x=0.35` (correct) for blue curve while `x=0.834` for green).

I know that `Show[]` takes the axes scaling of the first plot in its argument (here `p1`). But, I thought that instead of matching scales, `Show` would plot them using the `x,y` coordinates of the respective plots (I don't really know how `Show[]` combines plots with different scales but same value ranges). Since the `x,y` values are the same in both cases, (I don't know how `Show[]` would know that though), I expected them to coincide.

Alternatively, using `Show[p2,p1]` I get,

[image: pic4]

Also, why do they cross at exactly `y=Exp[1]`? Why in the last picture the blue plot `p1` is not horizontally till `x=10^(-3)`? How is it decided how to combine the plots? I feel I am missing something small but significant here. Thank you.

**EDIT 1:** Upon @kglr 's suggestion in the comment, I replaced `10^(x)` to `Exp^(x)` in `ContourPlot`. The blue curve changed (the green remains same) and now the graphs coincide! But, I still don't particularly understand how `Show[]` decides to combine them and why they were not coinciding initially...? Because now both look exactly like the green curve in pic3 above. Now thus, `y=Exp[Exp[x]]` and this matches e.g. at `y=10` in pic3. The `x=0.834` which means `y=Exp[Exp[0.834]]` which Is equal to `10`. So that means, `Show[]` is plotting `Exp[Exp[x]]` for `p2` in pic3 instead of `Exp[10^(x)]`. I find that weird. How did `Show[]` decide to do that? Thanks.

Comment: change  `10^(x)` to `E^(x)` in `func1[10^(x),y] == 0` in `ContourPlot`?

Comment: @kglr I tried (upon your asking). They coincide now! Thanks. But, I still don't understand why they are shifted in the first place? How does `Show[]` work?

Comment: odomosis, re _"why they were not coinciding initially"_, it is  because horizontal axis was scaled differently in `ContourPlot` and `LogLinearPlot`  (logarithm in base 10 vs natural log), That is, your _"fake" log-linear"_, `ContourPlot` is actually a _fake Log10-linear_ plot.

Comment: Yes. That is true. Let me think about this a bit more. You are right that this might be the key. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I would not close this question. I understand how base $e$ can be surprising and unusual for some new users, especially those not coming from math/physics. @kglr Can you post a short answer?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so spurred on by @kglr 's comments, I fiddled around with `Show[]` and plot scalings. This is what I conclude:

1. By default, `Show[p1,p2]` will always follow the scaling of the first plot `p1`.
2. If you have a plot `p2` on a `Log` scale (say on x-axis) in Mathematica, it means log to base "e" even though Mathematica shows markings in spaces of "10". So, in pic2 of the question, even though you see markings of "10" factors, instead of plotting `Exp[x]` with $x\in [10^{-3},10]$, Mathematica is actually plotting `Exp[Exp[z]]` with `z` such that $e^{z_{min}}=x_{min}=10^{-3}$ and $e^{z_{max}}=x_{max}=10$, i.e. $z\in [-6.9077,2.3025]$. This is the key to understanding scaling of log plots in Mathematica.
3. So, now, if you plot `Show[p1,p2]`, then Mathematica chooses the scaling of p1 and plots p1 as it is. p1 is basically a linear plot in x for $x\in [-3,1]$ which plots $e^{10^{x}}$. For p2, it plots `Exp[Exp[x]]` with $x\in [-3,1]$ (because it chose the linear scaling of p1). Thus, you can see that in pic3 of the question p2 reaches y=10 at x=0.834 ($e^{e^{0.834...}}\approx 10$). Also, because for p2 the actual range is $[-6.9077,2.3025]$ you can see it running off to the left beyond x=-3.
4. If you now plot `Show[p2,p1]` (pic4 in question) it will choose the scaling of `p2`. Thus, it will plot `p2` as it is. Now, again, even though the x-axis ticks show points from $10^{-3}$ to $10$ (the 10 got cut-off because I didn't put `PlotRange->All`), what is really plotted is `Exp[Exp[z]]` where the real x-axis values (behind the scenes) being $z\in [-6.9077,2.3025]$. Thus, since in p1 $x\in [-3,1]$, it will only plot p1 for $z\in [-3,1]$ i.e. the tick values will $\in [e^{-3},e^{1}]\equiv [0.04978,2.7182]$. But here, since p1 reaches y=10 at x=0.3622 ($e^{10^{0.3622...}}\approx 10$), the p1 plot gets cut-off due to plot range in y being only till 10 artifact. Thus, it is only visible till z-value of 0.3622 i.e. the tick value of $e^{0.3622...}=1.4365...$.
5. Thus, to make them both coincide in pic3 and pic4, just change the p1 function to $e^{e^{x}}$. Then you'll get the following two pictures respectively:

[image: pic5]

and

[image: pic6]

TLDR; A log axis in Mathematica is by default base "e" behind the scenes (even though the ticks are at intervals of 10). Further, the real x-coordinates are $z=\ln(\text{tick values})$ and not the tick values themselves.